# Pseudoinverse of $T: L^2(a,b) \to L^2(a,b)$, $f \mapsto g f$, where $g \in \mathcal{C}(a,b) \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, pseudoinverse

> Find the pseudoinverse $T^+$ of 
>   $$T: L^2(a,b) \to L^2(a,b), \ 
> f \mapsto g f,$$
>   where $0 \ne g \in \mathcal{C}(a,b)$.
>   First find $\mathcal{N}(T)$ and $\mathcal{R}(T)$ (which denote kernel and range, respectively) and their orthogonal complements. Then find $\widetilde{T}^{-1}$, where $\widetilde{T}: \mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp} \to \mathcal{R}(T)$ is the restriction of $T$ to $\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}$.

1. First I noticed that $T$ is unbounded, as $g f$ need not be in $L^2(a,b)$, i.e. pick $(a,b) := (0,1)$, $f := g := x^{-1/4}$.
   Then
   $$
   \| f \|_{L^2(0,1)}
   = \| g \|_{L^2(0,1)}
   = \int_0^1 x^{-1/2} dx = 2
   $$
   but
   $$
   \| f g \|_{L^2(0,1)}
   = \int_{0}^{1} |x^{-1/2}|^2 dx
   = \int_0^1 x^{-1} dx
   = \infty.
   $$
   Is this correct?  I am struggling with this as normally with unbounded operators we are given a domain $\text{dom}(T)$.
2. Let $G := \{ x \in (a,b): g(x) \ne 0\}$ I think that $\mathcal{N}(T) = \{ f \in L^2(a,b): f|_{G} = 0\}$. 
   Then we would have
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}
   & = \{ h \in L^2(a,b): \int_a^b h(x) j(x) dx = 0 \ \forall j \in \mathcal{N}(T)\} \\
   & = \{ h \in L^2(a,b): h(x) j(x) = 0 \ \forall j \in \mathcal{N}(T)\} \\
   & = \{ h \in L^2(a,b): h|_{G^{\complement}} = 0\}.
   \end{align}
   I only found $\mathcal{R}(T) = \{ f g: f \in L^2(a,b)\}$ and therefore
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}
   & = \{ h \in L^2(a,b): \int_{a}^{b} h(x) f(x) g(x) dx = 0: f g \in L^2(a,b) \} \\
   & = \{ h \in L^2(a,b): h|_{G} = 0\}
   = \mathcal{N}(T). 
   \end{align}
   Is this correct?
3. We would therefore have
   $$
   \widetilde{T}: \{ f \in L^2(a,b): f|_{{G^{\complement}}} = 0\} \to \{ f g: f \in L^2(a,b)\}, \ 
   f \mapsto f g.
   $$
   Thus $\widetilde{T}^{-1}$ is given by 
   $$
   \widetilde{T}^{-1}: \{ f g: f \in L^2(a,b)\} \to \{ f \in L^2(a,b): f|_{{G^{\complement}}} = 0\}, f \mapsto f / g
   $$
   and therefore 
   $$
   T^+: \mathcal{R}(T) \oplus \mathcal{N}(T) \to \mathcal{N}^{\perp}, f \mapsto f / g.
   $$

Comment: Ad 1) Yes, if you allow $g$ to be unbounded, then your operator will be unbounded. Ad 2) It is not necessarily true that the range is not closed. Consider for instance the case $g \equiv 1$. Also, I think you don't have to look at the support, but rather at the set $\{x : g(x) \neq 0\}$, without taking a closure. Consider for example the case where the zero set of $g$ is a fat Cantor set.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you very much for your comment. If have taken your suggestions into consideration and edited according. Is everything correct now? If yes, feel free to answer the question with your comment above.

Comment: Well just because $g \in \mathcal{C}(a,b)$, it must not be bounded, like $g = \tan$, $a = - \frac{\pi}{2}$, $b = \frac{\pi}{2}$, right?